# How do i traverse a html form and get descendants individually

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to read all elements of a html form so i can change the layout on the fly. the form container and content looks like this:

```
<label for="text-xplant" class="fx-text-label">Text Field</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="text-xplant" id="text-xplant">


<label for="textarea-xplant" class="fx-textarea-label">Text Area</label>
<textarea type="textarea" class="form-control" name="textarea-xplant" id="textarea-xplant"></textarea>


<label for="date-xplant" class="fx-date-label">Date Field</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="date-xplant" id="date-xplant">


<label for="select-xplant" class="fx-select-label">Select</label>
<select class="form-control" name="select-xplant" id="select-xplant">
<option value="option-1" selected="true" id="select-xplant-0">Option 1</option>
<option value="option-2" id="select-xplant-1">Option 2</option>
<option value="option-3" id="select-xplant-2">Option 3</option>
</select>


<label for="checkbox-group-xplant" class="fx-checkbox-group-label">Checkbox Group</label>
<div class="checkbox-group">
<div class="checkbox">
<input name="checkbox-group-xplant[]" id="checkbox-group-xplant-0" value="CheckValue1" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<label for="checkbox-group-xplant-0">CheckText1</label>
</div>
</div>


<label for="radio-group-xplant" class="fx-radio-group-label">Radio Group</label>
<div class="radio-group">
<div class="radio">
<input name="radio-group-xplant" id="radio-group-xplant-0" value="RadioValue1" type="radio">
<label for="radio-group-xplant-0">RadioText1</label>
</div>
</div>
```

My jQuery is as follows and i can get all the labels without a problem - but i cannot get the individual elements. Bearing in mind - these are the only 6 elements that will be in the form, but they could be in any order. Also some may not be present or there may be more than one of each element -though all have unique names and ids in keeping with html rules.

```
var cntxt, tblRowTH="", tblRowTD="", chk, rdo, txt, dte, txa, slc;

$('#fb-rendered-form .rendered-form > .form-group').each(function() 
{
// get table row headers / titles
tblRowTH += "<th>" + $(this).find('label').html() + "</th>";

// get table-row form controls - testing for each of our 6 control types -
// Note: .prop('outerHTML') as it gets tag AND content; .html() only gets content!
chk = $(this).find('.checkbox-group').prop('outerHTML')  || 'NoElem';   chk += "<td>"+chk+"</td>";
rdo = $(this).find('.radio-group').prop('outerHTML')     || 'NoElem';   rdo += "<td>"+rdo+"</td>";
txt = $(this).find('input[type=text]').prop('outerHTML') || 'NoElem';   txt += "<td>"+txt+"</td>";
dte = $(this).find('input[type=date]').prop('outerHTML') || 'NoElem';   dte += "<td>"+dte+"</td>";
txa = $(this).find('textarea').prop('outerHTML')         || 'NoElem';   txa += "<td>"+txa+"</td>";
slc = $(this).find('select').prop('outerHTML')           || 'NoElem';   slc += "<td>"+slc+"</td>";
});
```

Other than figuring out i need outerHTML to ensure i get the container as well as the markup within each container my output is full of 'undefined' output. As can be seen i want to make the labels into table headers and each corresponding element the row beneath.

What is the correct/better way to achieve this??

Comment: Looks like you should be using the `.wrap()` method of jQuery.

Comment: @ Barmar i tried that but my console.log says .wrap is not a function - problem being if the output is undefined you'd be trying to wrap it thats why i used 'NoElem'

Comment: You don't apply `.wrap()` to a string, you apply it to the jQuery objects themselves. `$(this).find(".checkbox-group").wrap("<td>")`

Comment: Ok didnt know that  - however the more pressing problem is im getting lines of 'undefined' strings since if an element isnt on the form (there can be zero or more instances of each label/control group on the form.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. If the selector doesn't match anything, there's nothing to wrap around. You must be using it wrong. You understand that this operates directly on the DOM, right? You don't need to assign the result anywhere.

Comment: Amending one line thus: chk = $(this).find('.checkbox-group').wrap("<td>"); - as you suggest yields this in the console:  w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(1)] - if i add the outerHTML() func: chk = $(this).find('.checkbox-group').prop('outerHTML').wrap("<td>"); then the console says:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wrap' of undefined

Comment: What do you need the outer HTML for? `.wrap()` modifies the DOM itself, it puts the `<td>` around the element.